# How to change foreground and background text color in console?

Tags: c#, colors, console

I'm writing a console C# program. I would like to change the foreground and the background color of the text in console.

Answer (score 10):

```
Console.BackgroundColor//t set the background color for the text.
Console.ForegroundColor//to set the foreground color for the text.
Console.ResetColor();//set back the foreground color and background color to the default.
```

Comment: So, no need to use the windows API!

Answer (score 7):

You need only to set

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

Read all about it at http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-color

Answer (score 5):

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.BackgroundColor = Console.Color.White;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following properties (links to MSDN documentation):

[Console.BackgroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.backgroundcolor.aspx)

[Console.ForegroundColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To set the foreground color of console text:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; // Changes console foreground to red
```

To set the text background color of console text

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue; // Changes console text background to blue
```

To set the actual console background color

```
// Changes console background color to green
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.Clear();
```